# Drupal: map address geolocation search

Tags: drupal, search, dictionary, geolocation

I am using the gmap and location modules to display a map. I would like the users to be able to fill an address in a field and the map autocenters and autozooms to that address. Like maps.google.com does it. 
Is there a module or any specific configuration I can do with drupal? Ultimately I would like to create an advance filter where user inputs country, province and address and posibly select from a drop down list. Something very similar to what it is done in the following link http://www.dei.gr/Default.aspx?id=30608&nt=18&lang=2&langid=1

Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of any modules that would do that. Have you thought of maybe creating your own module?

Answer (score 0):

The GMap Location Module is the one which fits the requirements most closely.
"Provides a map of all a site's nodes and a map of all of the site users."

If you'd like to create it by yourself:
Would suggest to create 2 tables - with labels and center-points - in order to populate these cascaded drop-downs.
The last input-box needs to geo-code the entered text - over the Google GeoCoder API.

Of course any centerpoint could be geo-coded - but you have a limit of 2.500 API requests per 24hrs on the PHP API,
unless being a premier customer (besides local results are just quicker). That's why it's recommend to store the center-points for each item in the drop-downs in a table - and only use the JS API (instead of the PHP API) for the last step.

The example which you provided reloads the whole page when changing the drop-downs, which should be avoided.